# Open default phone Contacts app with Expo

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, mobile, deep-linking

I'm using React Native Expo, and I want to open the default phone Contacts app.

**On Android, I used:**

```
await Linking.openURL("content://contacts/people/");
```

and that's worked.

On iOS that doesn't work.

**I tried:**

```
await Linking.openURL('contacts://');
```

but it doesn't work.
How do I do that on IOS?

I want to open the contacts app on the iPhone only. Not getting contact data from the device through my app as suggested in some answers.

Answer (score -1):

To open the default dialer app on iOS without a number pre-filled, you can try using the `telprompt://{your number}` URL scheme, which should prompt the dialer to open without immediately initiating a call. Here’s how you might use it in React Native

```
 import { Linking } from 'react-native';

// Function to open the dialer
const openDialer = async () => {
  const url = 'telprompt://<<your Number>>';
  const supported = await Linking.canOpenURL(url);

  if (supported) {
    await Linking.openURL(url);
  } else {
    console.log('Unable to open dialer');
  }
};
```

Comment: I don't want to access the contacts in my app. I just want to open the contact app, or at least - the default dial app without any number there.
I know tel:1234 but it makes a popup of the number, not open the dial app.

Comment: i just change answer please check

Comment: That's doesn't work. It opens a popup with an empty title and content with two buttons: Call and Cancel. Pressing on each button closes the popup but does nothing and does not open the dial app.

Comment: you want to add your number

Comment: Thank you for your answers. It doesn't do what I want, I want to open a separate app (Dial or Contact).  I see that this is not possible.  I don't want to call a number, I just want to open the default apps as I did on Android.

Comment: it's working or not ?

Comment: It doesn't work mate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257259/discussion-between-segev-gr-and-mahammad-momin).